# Angularjs chained select with 4 select options make empty on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, chained

I have the following problem: When i implement a chained select with for example 4 selects and i update the second one the third one gets empty but the fourth one keeps the value. Here is a link to jsfiddle with the strategy i used to make the chained select (This fiddle was not made by me!):

http://jsfiddle.net/pythondave/JUZDf/

1. select Classic cars
2. select 1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster
3. select Color
4. select Red
5. select 1949 Jaguar XK 120

Now you see that the fourth select doesn't get empty
How can you make that one empty?

HTML part:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="SelectController">
 <select ng-model="category" ng-options="c.name for c in sampleProductCategories">    </select>
 <select ng-model="categoryItem" ng-options="p.name for p in category.products"></select>
 <select ng-model="subChild" ng-options="o.value for o in categoryItem.options"></select>
 <select ng-model="level4" ng-options="o.value for o in subChild.options"></select>

  <hr />
  category={{category.name}}<br/>
  product={{categoryItem.name}}<br/>
  subChild={{subChild.value}}<br/>
  level4={{level4.value}}<br/>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function SelectController($scope) {
    // Data taken from KnockoutJs cart example
    $scope.sampleProductCategories = [
      {
        "name": "Classic Cars",
          "products": [
          {
            "name": "1948 Porsche 356-A Roadster",
              "options":[
                  {"value": "Color",
                   "options":[
                  {"value": "Red"},
                  {"value":"Black"}
                  ],                                    
               },
                  {"value":"Seats",
                  "options":[
                  {"value": "Leather"},
                  {"value":"Cloth"}
                  ],    

                  },

                 {"value":"Warranty",
                  "options":[
                  {"value": "2 Year"},
                  {"value":"3 Year"}
                  ],    

                  } 

              ],
            "price": 53.9
          },
          {
            "name": "1948 Porsche Type 356 Roadster",
            "price": 62.16
          },
          {
            "name": "1949 Jaguar XK 120",
            "price": 47.25
          }
        ]

      },
      {
        "name": "Motorcycles",
        "products": [
          {
            "name": "1936 Harley Davidson El Knucklehead",
            "price": 24.23
          },
          {
            "name": "1957 Vespa GS150",
            "price": 32.95
          },
          {
            "name": "1960 BSA Gold Star DBD34",
            "price": 37.32
          }
        ]

      },
      {
        "name": "Planes",
          "products": [
          {
            "name": "1900s Vintage Bi-Plane",
            "price": 34.25
          },
          {
            "name": "1900s Vintage Tri-Plane",
            "price": 36.23
          },
          {
            "name": "1928 British Royal Navy Airplane",
            "price": 66.74
          },
          {
            "name": "1980s Black Hawk Helicopter",
            "price": 77.27
          },
          {
            "name": "ATA: B757-300",
            "price": 59.33
          }
        ]

      }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a new select value is being selected it is only changing the model variable linked to that select box, the remainder are unchanged. So despite selecting a new value for `categoryItem`, `subChild` still retains its value from anything previously selected, and it is this value the forth select box builds it's options from, thus retaining the values. You will see the same result when using any of the first 3 select boxes.

You could use the `ng-change` directive to execute a function on the select box change to reset the required scope variables:

```
<select ng-model="category" ng-change="update(select1)" ng-options="c.name for c in sampleProductCategories">    </select>
<select ng-model="categoryItem" ng-change="update(select2)" ng-options="p.name for p in category.products"></select>
```

Then in your controller:

```
function SelectController($scope) {
    $scope.update = function (select) {
        // update the appropriate n-selectBoxNum scope variables here
    }
}
```